# Can't login to docker private registry after updating SSL certificates

Tags: docker

I recently made an update to SSL certificate on the domain hosting my docker private repository. Now I am not able to login to it on my linux server. I get the following error

```
 x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I was encountering same problem on local windows machine, however restarting docker seemed to work. I have now many times tried to do the same on the linux server but restarting docker is not working. The error is persistent.

Does docker caches previous login information ? (like SSL certificate key etc.)
How can I flush (clear cache) and force docker to make a fresh login request?

I used letsencrypt to generate a certificate.

Thanks

Comment: how did you create the certificate? if it is self-signed you will need to install it manually on your system

Comment: i used letesencrypt

Comment: So I'm pretty sure you didn't config your registry correctly, and the answers here won't solve your problem the right way (this workaround they are suggesting isn't good for the long-term). I suggest you to edit the question and add more data about the certificate it self.

Comment: @Mogi, I agree with you, what more information about the certificate should I provide to fix it the proper way. i agree  that below solutions seems like a hack

Comment: Tell how you created the certificate, where did you put it on the registry and more details about the registry. I'm pretty sure the problem is within the registry not with your client setup

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution:

- Edit or create the file /etc/docker/daemon.json and add insecure-registries :

example for docker.example.org:

```json
{
    "insecure-registries" : ["docker.example.org:443"]
}
```

- Restart docker daemon

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Is it not a hack?? It is working on my local machine without the need for this flagging. i used letxsencrypt to generate the certificate

Comment: the author's certificate isn't self-signed, so this answer isn't recommended (he should add more details about the certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Above answer1 is correct. Use `insecure-registries` flag to avoid  `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` Or Add ca.crts in docker.

Comment: On the linux server that hosts the registry as a docker container with a nginx load-balancer containing the correct SSL certificates, I am not able to do docker login <registry.domain.com> . it works from my local machine .. why should it be insecure-registry ?? is it not a hack to add this flag?

Comment: the author's certificate isn't self-signed, so this answer isn't recommended (he should add more details about the certificate)